# 7zip - powershell - exclude files in "listfile"

Tags: powershell, 7zip

I want to compress a folder using 7zip via powershell-Script. This folder contains a specific sub directory "\pdfs", which contains a lot of pdf-files. I want to keep only the latest pdf within this directory.
My code is this:

```
$Date = get-date -format "yyy-MM-dd"
$ThisFolder = Get-Location 
$ziptargetFolder = Split-Path -parent $ThisFolder
$folder     = (Get-Item $ThisFolder)
$folderName = $folder.Name
$excludingpdflist =""
$PDFFolder = -join ("$ThisFolder", "\pdfs")

$ziptarget = -join("$ziptargetFolder", "\", "$Date", "_", "$folderName", ".zip")
$ExcludeFilelist = -join("$ziptargetFolder", "\ExcludeFiles.txt")

$ExludeBackupFolder = -join("$ThisFolder", "\ProjectBackup\backups")

Get-ChildItem "$PDFFolder" | Sort CreationTime | Select Object -SkipLast 1  -ExpandProperty Name |Out-File "$ExcludeFilelist" -encoding ascii

$excludingzips = -join("-xr!", "*.zip")
$excludingpdfs = -join("-x!", "*\*.pdf")
$excludingpdflist = -join("-x@", "$ExcludeFilelist") 

$zipExePath= "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"

[Array]$zipArgs = "a", "-tzip", "$ziptarget", "$ThisFolder", "$excludingzips", "$excludingpdfs", "$excludingpdflist"

& $zipExePath $zipArgs
```

The code-line

```
Get-ChildItem "$PDFFolder" | Sort CreationTime | Select Object -SkipLast 1  -ExpandProperty Name |Out-File "$ExcludeFilelist" -encoding ascii
```

creates a txt file, that contains every file but the latest in the "\pdfs"-directory  - these files should be excluded from the zip-Archiv, but aren't.

```
MyFile.Rev0100.pdf 
MyFile.Rev0101.pdf 
MyFile.Rev0102.pdf
MyFile.Rev0103.pdf
```

I also tried the "full name" of the files to be excluded:

```
Get-ChildItem "$PDFFolder" | Sort CreationTime | Select Object -SkipLast 1  -ExpandProperty FullName |Out-File "$ExcludeFilelist" -encoding ascii
```

This code results in this output:

```
C:\MyDirectories\pdfs\MyFile.Rev0100.pdf
C:\MyDirectories\pdfs\MyFile.Rev0101.pdf
C:\MyDirectories\pdfs\MyFile.Rev0102.pdf
C:\MyDirectories\pdfs\MyFile.Rev0103.pdf
```

I also tried to *include* the latest file, but this didn't work either; code changes to:

```
Get-ChildItem "$PDFFolder" | Sort CreationTime -Descending | Select Object -First 1  -ExpandProperty Name |Out-File "$IncludeFilelist" -encoding ascii # txt contains: MyFile.Rev0104.pdf
...
$Includingpdflist = -join("-i@", "$IncludeFilelist")
...
```

What am I doing wrong? Or what have I to do, to exclude those files?

Comment: Try to specify relative paths, e. g. `pdfs\MyFile.Rev0100.pdf`. Make sure current directory (specified via `Set-Location`) is set to base directory of files to zip.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. I exclude the whole "\pdfs"-directory, but include the latest file - this file will be written in the root-directory of the zip. Now I use 7zip function "rn" to rename the pdf in the zip-file:

```
$Date = get-date -format "yyy-MM-dd"
$ThisFolder = Get-Location 
$ziptargetFolder = Split-Path -parent $ThisFolder
$folder     = (Get-Item $ThisFolder)
$folderName = $folder.Name
$PDFFolder = -join ("$ThisFolder", "\pdfs")
$ziptarget = -join("$ziptargetFolder", "\", "$Date", "_", "$folderName", ".zip")

$latest = (Get-ChildItem "$PDFFolder" | Sort-Object CreationTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1)
$includelatestPDF = -join("-ir!", ".\pdfs\", "$latest")#".Name") #Name 

$excludingzips = -join("-xr!", "*.zip")
$excludingpdfs = -join("-x!", "*\*.pdf") #ignor pdfs in root directory (not xr! - just x!)

$excludingpdfsfolder = -join("-xr!", "*\pdfs\*.pdf")

$zipExePath= "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"

[Array]$zipArgs = "a", "-tzip", "-ssw", "$ziptarget", "$ThisFolder", "$excludingzips", "$excludingpdfs", "$excludingpdfsfolder", "$includelatestPDF"

& $zipExePath $zipArgs

$src= $latest.Name
$rename = -join("$folderName", "\pdfs\", "$src")
[Array]$zipArgs = "rn", "$ziptarget", "$src", "$rename"

& $zipExePath $zipArgs
```